# Visual studio indent string

Tags: c#, visual-studio

having this string

```
var commandAfterSerialize = $@"{{""LotId"":""00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"",""AuctionId"":""00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"",""DisableTotalSpendUpdate"":false,""AltInternetSurchargeRate"":null,""WinningBidders"":{{""{winningBidderKey}"":true,""{winningBidderKeySecond}"":false}},""Timestamp"":{timeStampUtc.Ticks},""TimestampUtc"":""{timeStampUtc:o}""}}";
```

is it possible to display it in better way in visual studio (for editing purpose) without modifing string itself ? without inserting `\r\n` into it ?

better formating like json

I am using visual studio 2022, c# 6.0

Comment: Depends. What C# Version are you on? => [raw strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/raw-string)

Comment: @Fildor studio 2022, c# 6.0

Comment: What does "in better way" mean? How does Visual Studio matter? It's just a text editor.

Comment: @gunr2171better formating like json

Comment: It's a language feature. The editor has nothing to do with that. C# 11 introduces raw strings, I think.

Comment: @gunr2171 - that’s the point to visualize it better inside the editor, so not one long unformatted string, but instead a well formatted, well indented string

Comment: Are you wanting to display the resulting variable value or reformat the _source code_? If it's the latter you can span strings across multiple lines by using `" + {\r\n} "` witohut adding line breaks to the string value itself. Or use a string literal that contains whitespace.

Comment: Granted, this is an X/Y problem. Use a JSON parsing library instead of trying to construct it using literals.

Comment: If you want to embed larger, more complex JSON in your app, better to put them in a resource file anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## C# 11

Allows you to use [raw string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/raw-string)

Example taken from the linked resource:

```
var xml = """
        <element attr="content">
            <body>
            </body>
        </element>
        """;
```

## Older C# versions

You can do something like this:

```
var xml = "<element attr=\"content\">"+
          "  <body>"+
          "  </body>"+
          "</element>";
```

Nevermind the XML, this works of course with any string content.

---

Outside these, I'd like to second @DavidG's comment:

> If you want to embed larger, more complex JSON in your app, better to put them in a resource file

Which has further advantages, as for example you could validate the json. You can have json-specific editor behavior, etc.

Comment: Would a resource file be the best option when the OP is interpolating the string?  Probably better to create classes that represent the JSON and use serialization.

Comment: @maccettura I assumed a literal, yes. If we are talking about interpolation, or even actual data serialization, then that's a whole different story.

Comment: @maccettura Although you _can_ interpolate a raw string ... I don't think there is a "always right" solution, here. You always have to look at what you are dealing with and pick your tools.